# bash list files ctime - filename - and first line from each file?

Tags: bash

I have few files in a directory. I need to display, in a bash script, the columns:

Files in directory /reports/:

```
ctime - filename - 1st line text
```

[I've found the perfect soluton here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59249/print-output-to-3-separate-columns)

```
#!/bin/sh

MYPATH=/
TOTALFILE=$(ls $MYPATH/* | wc -l)
FILE=$(ls -1tcr $MYPATH/* | head -5 | rev | cut -d/ -f1 | rev)

declare -a FILES
declare -a FILETIME

OUTPUT="FILENAME CREATED TIME ERROR_HEADER\n\n------------------------------ ----------------------------- ----------------------------------- ------$

for i in $MYPATH/*;
do
    FILES[${#FILES[@]}]="$i"
    FILETIME[${#FILETIME[@]}]=$(stat --format=%y $i | head -5 | cut -d'.' -f1)
    TOPLINE=$(head -1 $i | grep -Po '".*?"' | head -5)

    OUTPUT="$OUTPUT\n${FILES[${#FILES[@]}-1]} ${FILETIME[${#FILETIME[@]}-1]} $TOPLINE\n"
done

echo -ne $OUTPUT | column -t
```

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -type f -printf '%a %p ' -exec head -n1 {} \;
```

see

```
man find
```

Sounds like a *homework*. Right ? =)

Comment: `find . -type f -printf '%a %p ' -exec head -n1 {} \; | grep -oP "regex"`

Comment: your answer is incorrect in terms of formatting. EASIEST solution not always good one...

Answer (score 2):

`find /reports -type f | xargs ls -lt` 
this is sorted by create time,so the newest file is on the top
if you want only one result, you can add `head -n 1 or head -1` after the command with `|`
Hope helps.